# How to get length of a string column in Athena?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

How to get length of a `VARCHAR` or `STRING` column in AWS Athena? The AWS Documentation doesn't give any information on a length function, which works equivalent to the `LEN()` function in Redshift.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Presto's `length()` functions works for getting the size of a `STRING`/`VARCHAR` column.

Usage : `length(column_name)`